# Why is icon on retina device not showing up?

Tags: iphone, retina-display

I have an iPhone app that is apparently not displaying its icon on the home/desktop screen only on a retina iPhone device.

I can see the icons in the retina simulator, as well as regular iPhone simulator.
I can see the icon on my iPad2 device as well.

My Xcode plist has two key/values:

1. "icon file" set to icon.png
2. "icon files" with item 0 set to icon.png

The single icon.png that I have included in my project is a 144 x 144 png image (I figured i'd just create one high resolution icon image that both the regular and retina iPhones will use, rather than going thru the duplication of icon files with the retina version being appended @2x.png).

Im curious why this isn't working on the retina iPhone device, since having a single icon.png should still display it on all iPhones (ex: retina iPhone can still display 72 x 72 icons).

anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe you need too add the @2x at the end so you will have to provide both images, also if you plan on submitting to Apple you have to have a standard and a high res Apple guidelines state.

Comment: In the past i have successfully submitted apps that does not support retina displays. Retina devices simply shows fuzzy images due to the images being stretched out. Perhaps something changed to no longer support this?

Comment: I submit apps to Apple for my team and a couple of others ... I've only noticed them getting kicked back for missing retina images in the last couple of months, so perhaps they were not enforcing the inclusion of high-res images previously. Then again, I don't remember for sure when I last submitted an app prior to the last few weeks.

Comment: I just know when I read the Apple submission guidelines it states that there should be a standard res and high res icon image. Possibility is because 3GS is still supported. But with the release of the next iPhone coming very soon I can imagine this will be dropped from Apples support list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's working in the simulator as it is my understanding that it shouldn't. As with all other images in your application, you should create density-specific resources and name them appropriately.

[Per the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html), you should have two images, and they should be in your project's root folder:

1. icon.png (57x57)
2. icon@2x.png (114x114)

Comment: +1. *Always* go with the docs in things like this - you can't get away with shortcuts like just making one image when two are explicitly called for, just because you don't feel like "going through the duplication."